# Can we reduce Time complexity O(n) of preparing a Java HashSet from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, time-complexity

There is an `ArrayList` of 10000+ items. I am trying to make them unique through a `HashSet` which is a operation of O(n) complexity. Is there any other algorithm / DS which can make a `Collection` unique with lower complexity than O(n)?

Comment: Anything special in the nature of the array elements? Any pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is literally impossible.  O(n) is the minimum complexity to so much as read through the `ArrayList`, let alone do anything with the elements.

Comment: "literally impossible" -- I would be careful with using it like that. Some said sorting in linear time was impossible. Now in this case with a HashSet and ArrayList it is though!

Comment: @Emz...what?  No, that doesn't make sorting in linear time possible.

Comment: @Emz You may find it shocking that ["literally" now has a definition which simply places emphasis on something which is actually not literal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/literally). So he could always claim that if it were to turn out to be possible. It won't though.

Comment: Not in this case, I just pointed out that stating x is "literally impossible" was maybe a bit courageously to use. And I gave an example to back it up.

Comment: @DoubleDouble, I know that, I never stated that it was wrong. I said I would be careful. I was to be taken *literally*!

Comment: No, I'm quite comfortable stating that uniquifying in less than O(n) time is impossible in any sense, and I don't understand why you claim that "in this case with a HashSet and ArrayList" sorting is possible in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Without going through all the elements once, it is not possible to confirm that your set has all unique values. Hence, O(n) is minimum possible.

Comment: That got me thinking, if you store them sorted and use a binary search to find the key? If you don't find it then voila, you can insert it.

Comment: Doing for each key will make it n*logn